# Convert a class instance to a Dictionary for iteration

Tags: c#, json.net

I want a generic function to convert any class instance to a dict so i can easily work with it in a generic fashion. In my case i want to convert any instance `SSF.Mod` to a dict that i can iterate over to dynamically generate part of the UI based on it.

I thought about using json.net but upon quick inspection i have seen noone ever asking for the excact same thing.

Cut down version of SSF.Mod class:

```cs
namespace SSF
{
    public class FileWithHash
    {
        public string PrivatePath { get; set; }
        public FileWithHash(string sharedPath, string hash)
        {
            PrivatePath = sharedPath; Hash = hash;
        }
    }
        public class Mod
        {
            [JsonIgnore]
            private Game Game { get; set; }
            public bool Disabled {
                get { ... }
            }
            public string Id { get; set; }
            public DirectoryInfo Directory { get; set; }
            public FileWithHash GroFile { get; set; }
            public FileWithHash Thumbnail { get; set; }
            public Publishedfiledetail Details { get; set; }
            public List<string> Tags { get {
                if (Details is null) return null;
                var ret = new List<string>();
                foreach (var tag in Details.tags) {
                    ret.Add(tag.tag);
                }
                return ret;
            } }
     }
}
```

Cut down example instace as json:

```
{
  "Disabled": false,
  "Id": "1805661862",
  "Directory": {
    "OriginalPath": "S:\\Steam\\steamapps\\workshop\\content\\564310\\1805661862",
    "FullPath": "S:\\Steam\\steamapps\\workshop\\content\\564310\\1805661862"
  },
  "WorkshopVersion": "WorkshopVersion_01",
  "GroFile": {
    "PrivatePath": "Gro_File/DeepValley.gro",
    "Hash": "B68F60F4C87077DAF59F684B0306963BA6D4B351"
  },
  "Details": {
    "publishedfileid": "1805661862",
    "result": 1,
    "creator": "76561198016985053",
    "creator_app_id": 564380,
    "consumer_app_id": 564310,
    "filename": "",
  }
```

I thought about something like

```
Dictionary<string, object> dictOfMod = instanceOfMod.toDict();
foreach(var entry in dictOfMod){
   if (entry is bool) etc...
```

Comment: Why would you want to do this? It doesn't make sense. Then why do you create a class in the first place and not a `Dictionary`? This is possible but requires reflection...

Comment: If i can skip the json part that would be nice aswell

Comment: @BionicCode in all other parts of the code i want to get typehints and stuff and don't want to access the object like instance["thing1"]. I need it just there as a dict

Comment: I don't understand. You access members of an instance like `instance.Property` and get compiler support. Dictionary would be of type object with no compiler support since you 'erased' the types.

Comment: Once you say you are intending to create a UI of it, what kind of UI are we talking about here? Maybe you are thinking of an `IDictionary` but there might be tons better classes suitable for UI, depending on the framework and what you would like to do with it. Don't get me wrong, the answer by @BionicCode fits exactly your question, but this might as well be an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) where you might not know the best answer

Comment: Also, you might need to look into some details here, having `Tags` return `null` when details is empty, will require `null` checking on `Tags`, you might as well return `Enumerable.Empty<string>()`. For the rest, it will create a `new List<string>()` upon every request of `Tags`, I am not sure you really want that (for example, when converting it to a dictionary, it will create a new list of strings, once you want to modify that list in your base class, you wouldn't have the means to do it (so you should rather type is as `IEnumerable<string>` or `IReadonlyList<string>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert an instance to a `Dictionary`:

```
Mod mod = new Mod();

var modDictionary = mod.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
         .ToDictionary(
           propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name,
           propertyInfo => propertyInfo.GetValue(mod));
```

---

### Edit

The following method converts a type and its complete declaration type tree to a `Dictionary<string, object>`

## Remarks

The default `Key` of the `Dictionary<string, object>` is the property name.

Collections are converted to `Dictionary<string, object>` where the `Key` is the item's index.
The last item of such a dictionary is the count where the `Key` is `"Count"`.
To determine if a `Dictionary<string, object>` is a collection use the `Key` `"IsCollection"` which returns a boolean value.

You can use this extension method:

**Extensions.cs**

```
public static class Extensions
{
  public static Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary(this object instanceToConvert)
  {
    Dictionary<string, object> resultDictionary = instanceToConvert.GetType()
      .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
      .Where(propertyInfo => !propertyInfo.GetIndexParameters().Any())
      .ToDictionary(
        propertyInfo => propertyInfo.Name,
        propertyInfo => Extensions.ConvertPropertyToDictionary(propertyInfo, instanceToConvert));
    resultDictionary.Add("IsCollection", false);
    return resultDictionary;
  }

  private static object ConvertPropertyToDictionary(PropertyInfo propertyInfo, object owner)
  {
    Type propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
    object propertyValue = propertyInfo.GetValue(owner);
    if (propertyValue is Type)
    {
      return propertyValue;
    }

    // If property is a collection don't traverse collection properties but the items instead
    if (!propertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) && typeof(IEnumerable).IsAssignableFrom(propertyType))
    {
      var items = new Dictionary<string, object>();
      var enumerable = propertyInfo.GetValue(owner) as IEnumerable;
      int index = 0;
      foreach (object item in enumerable)
      {
        // If property is a string stop traversal
        if (item.GetType().IsPrimitive || item is string)
        {
          items.Add(index.ToString(), item);
        }
        else if (item is IEnumerable enumerableItem)
        {
          items.Add(index.ToString(), ConvertIEnumerableToDictionary(enumerableItem));
        }
        else
        {
          Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = item.ToDictionary();
          items.Add(index.ToString(), dictionary);
        }

        index++;
      }

      items.Add("IsCollection", true);
      items.Add("Count", index);
      return items;
    }

    // If property is a string stop traversal
    if (propertyType.IsPrimitive || propertyType.Equals(typeof(string)))
    {
      return propertyValue;
    }

    PropertyInfo[] properties =
      propertyType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Instance);
    if (properties.Any())
    {
      Dictionary<string, object> resultDictionary = properties.ToDictionary(
        subtypePropertyInfo => subtypePropertyInfo.Name,
        subtypePropertyInfo => propertyValue == null
          ? null
          : (object) Extensions.ConvertPropertyToDictionary(subtypePropertyInfo, propertyValue));
      resultDictionary.Add("IsCollection", false);
      return resultDictionary;
    }

    return propertyValue;
  }

  private static Dictionary<string, object> ConvertIEnumerableToDictionary(IEnumerable enumerable)
  {
    var items = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    int index = 0;
    foreach (object item in enumerable)
    {
      // If property is a string stop traversal
      if (item.GetType().IsPrimitive || item is string)
      {
        items.Add(index.ToString(), item);
      }
      else
      {
        Dictionary<string, object> dictionary = item.ToDictionary();
        items.Add(index.ToString(), dictionary);
      }

      index++;
    }

    items.Add("IsCollection", true);
    items.Add("Count", index);
    return items;
  }
}
```

## Example

```
// Test object definition
class TestClass
{
  public TestClass()
  {
    this.TheNestedList = new List<List<double>>() {new List<double>() {1, 2, 3, 4}, new List<double>() {11, 22, 33, 44}};
  }

  public List<List<double>> TheNestedList { get; set; }
}

// Usage example
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  var testClass = new TestClass();

  // Convert testClass instance to Dictionary<string, object>
  Dictionary<string, object> testClassDictionary = testClass.ToDictionary();

  // Consume the result and 
  // retrieve the outer List<List<double>>
  var nestedListProperty = testClassDictionary["NestedList"] as Dictionary<string, object>;

  if ((bool) nestedListProperty["IsCollection"])
  {
    // Retrieve the inner List<double>
    for (var index = 0; index < (int) theNestedListProperty["Count"]; index++)
    {
      var itemOfOuterList = theNestedListProperty[index.ToString()] as Dictionary<string, object>;
      if ((bool) itemOfOuterList["IsCollection"])
      {
        // Retrieve the double values
        for (var nestedListIndex = 0; nestedListIndex < (int) itemOfOuterList["Count"]; nestedListIndex++)
        {
          var innerListValue = (double) itemOfOuterList[nestedListIndex.ToString()];
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, now i just have to find out how to make it recursive :c

Comment: What do you mean? You want to convert sub types to dictionaries to, like a JSON?

Comment: Yes because subtypes can have subtypes aswell (https://hastebin.com/gixudabupa.cs is what i got so far)

Comment: @Bluescream I updated the answer. The new code also converts `public` properties into `Dictionary<string, object>`. For convenience I created an Extension Method. Be careful when a type is composed of an instance of its own type: recursion will run until the stack overflows. I also didn't tested the performance for deep type nesting (big type trees).

Comment: With your updated response i sadly get a `System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.' CS$<>8__locals0.propertyValue was null.` error in the line `if (!propertyType.Equals(typeof(string)) && (typeof(ICollection<>).Name.Equals(propertyValue.GetType().BaseType.Name) || typeof(Collection<>).Name.Equals(propertyValue.GetType().BaseType.Name)))`

Comment: @Bluescream I've tested the code and it is working. The object you are trying to convert must have some uninitialized properties. Please set a debugger break point to this line and check which reference is `null`. Then make sure that no property is `null`. If you need `null` properties add nulll-checks to the code.

Comment: could you please comment on the relevant repo for the sake of actual readability? https://github.com/Bluscream/Serious-Sam-Fusion-Mod-Manager/blob/master/SSFModManager/UI/MainForm.cs#L141

Comment: Ok, but what exactly should I comment on your repo? I didn't comitt any code there?

Comment: By the way, have you fixed the `NullReferenceException`?

Comment: @Bluescream I improved the implementation and the example. Can please check if the exception is fixed?